# How do I show in PowerBI a total average column based the number of columns shown by slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax, average

I have a matrix visualisation structured in a similar way to this:

| Employee | January | February | March | April | May | April | May | June | July | August | September | Total | Total (Average) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fred White | 5 | 10 | 5 | 10 | 15 | 10 | 5 | 10 | 5 | 10 | 5 | 90 | 10.00 |
| John Brown | 10 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 10 | 10 | 5 | 5 | 15 | 5 | 5 | 80 | 8.89 |
| Total | 15 | 15 | 10 | 15 | 25 | 20 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 15 | 10 | 170 | 18.89 |

I am trying to create a measure that will give me the Total (Average) value as above. The values are SUM of entries and not an AVERAGE of entries.

I have a slicer that controls the time period and the above is when Last 9 calendar months is set.

If I were to change the slicer to be Last 3 months then I would expect to see this:

| Employee | July | August | September | Total | Total (Average) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fred White | 5 | 10 | 5 | 20 | 6.67 |
| John Brown | 15 | 5 | 5 | 25 | 8.34 |

I created a simple measure:

Avg/Month = DIVIDE(SUM('tableA'[timeBooked]), DISTINCTCOUNT('tableA'[DateTime].[Month]))

I know the above is not correct for several reasons:

It ignores my slicer and returns a count of all distinct months in the data so is always dividing the sum total by 12 so the Total (Average) column is incorrect.

The matrix may be rolled up to years or expanded down to days so hard coding month in the calculation isn't correct. The data contains information multiple entries per day so there can be more than one entry per resource per day.

The slicer might say Last 18 months so a number of months will appear more than once and it will still only divide by 10

I have tried to find a way to incorporate the filtering of the slicer into the calculation but with no success and I cannot find an example of a solution that matches my scenario.

I am looking to create the average as the sum of the time booked / the number of columns in the calculation. For a single month column it it time booked in the month/1 whereas for the total (average) it is the total sum of time booked for the filtered period / number of columns in the filtered period.

It is identifying the count of columns being displayed that I am struggling with.  If showing last 9 months then I want to get a count of 9, if last 3 months then 3, if last 3 months but matrix expanded to show days then it would be 92.

I thought this kind of thing would be easy/built-in in power bi but it appears not.

I am a relative novice on DAX so be gentle and I appreciate any assistance you can provide. Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Hi @spendrake. I recommend you to create a date table first with day cardinality, and make use of time intelligence functions to filter your intended result (Last 9 month, Last 3 month, Last 7 days etc.. ) This is one of the best BI practices to follow, and you will also have many options to filter if you decide to filter by any other date feature in the future.